How to create custom URL in a one-pager?
I am developing a website using Kirby CMS, and the commission demands that the site remains a one-pager.
I am using the following structure where each article can be created in the panel, and customized (text, style, images …etc)
<?php foreach ($page->articles()->toStructure() as $article): ?>
    <div class="main" id="article-<?= $article->slug() ?>">
        <div class="container" onclick="toggleSibling(this);">
            <div class="Title"><?= $article->title() ?></div>
            <div class="Genre"><?= $article->genre() ?></div>
            <div class="Publisher"><?= $article->publisher() ?></div>
            <div class="Datum"><?= $article->datum()->toDate('m/Y') ?></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Apply the selected style dynamically -->
        <div class="content <?= $article->style() ?>">
            <div class="Info">
                <!-- <p>Information</p> -->
                <?= $article->info()->kt() ?>
            </div>
            <div class="Image">
            <!-- <p>Gallery</p> -->
                <div class="swiper">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <?php foreach ($article->images()->toFiles() as $image): ?>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <img src="<?= $image->url() ?>" alt="<?= $image->alt() ?>">
                            </div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
                    <button class="slick-prev"></button>
                    <button class="slick-next"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Page">
            <!-- <p>Index</p> -->
            </div>
            <div class="Text">
            <!-- <p>Content</p> -->
                <?= $article->text()->kt() ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>

The way it works is that each time an article is clicked, the main content becomes visible, which is executed with the following code:
function toggleSibling(element) {
  const content = element.nextElementSibling;

  // Close all other active content elements
  const allContent = document.querySelectorAll('.content.active');
  allContent.forEach(openContent => {
    if (openContent !== content) {
      openContent.classList.remove('active');
      Array.from(openContent.children).forEach(child => {
        child.style.transform = "";
        child.style.opacity = "";
        child.style.transition = "";
      });
    }
  });

  // Toggle the active class on sibling content
  content.classList.toggle('active');

  if (content.classList.contains('active')) {
    // Add the falling animation
    content.classList.add('fall');
    setTimeout(() => {
      content.classList.remove('fall');
      console.log("Falling animation removed from:", content); // Debugging animation reset
    }, 500);
  } else {
    // Reset styles if content is closed
    content.classList.remove('active');
    Array.from(content.children).forEach(child => {
      child.style.transform = "";
      child.style.opacity = "";
      child.style.transition = "";
    });
  }
}

What I am trying to implement is a way to utilize custom URL's for each article. When a user accesses said URL, it takes them to the article and toggles the content.
The page should remain a one-pager.
Thank you for the help in advance!

I suggest you remove one of the tags in favor of [tag:deep-linking].

Add the article id of the selected article as query string parameter ... something like ?id=12345. That gives you a unique URL without requiring any fancy config in your CMS or web server. You can also check the query string as the page loads and, if it matches an article, display the that article. I can provide further help in a day or two.

Thank you! Could you elaborate on how to implement this using the current code?
Thank you in advance! :)
